# Applet cannot recognize relative path on Tomcat Service?

Tags: java, tomcat, applet, jasper-reports

I got some errors in my app. The app is using applet for accessing local file system. 
converting file, for example.

**First:** Using relative path.
I can place project  folder wherever I need and the application still working properly. However, when I placed it on the tomcat server directory, it cannot find the files' path.

1. Run with browser: file:///C:/report-param/index.html, ok
2. Run with browser: localhost:8080/report-param/index.html, error

**Second:** Using absolute path. 
The application working well in both browser and tomcat server.

1. Run with browser: file:///C:/report-param/index.html, ok
2. Run with browser: localhost:8080/report-param/index.html, ok

Here is my sample code:

```
File jrxmlPath = new File("reports//people-report-withparam-multi.jrxml");
File pdfPath = new File("reports//people-report-withparam-multi.pdf");
String sourceJrxml = jrxmlPath.getPath();
String destPdf = pdfPath.getPath();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceJrxml);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, paramMap, 
            getPostgreSQLDataSource(driverUrl, username, password));
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,destPdf);
```

What is the matter on here? Any ideas?

How can I fix the error above? Please help...

*Note:* if you don't understand, feel free to ask me...

Comment: `File jrxmlPath = new File("reports//people-report-withparam-multi.jrxml");` Is this code on the server (e.g. JSP/servlet) or in the applet?  If 'applet' it needs to be something like `URL jrxmlPath = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "reports/people-report-withparam-multi.jrxml");`

Comment: Actually, I created the applet display interface on browser. On the browser, there are some action events. One of them executed the above code. To the `jrxmlPath`, it is in the applet code.

Comment: Just a question!! If I run applet html in `localhost:8080` and project folder is `sample`, what is `getDocumentBase()` is.

Comment: Generally, applets run within a security sandbox, which prevents them from access the local file system, have a look at [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) for more details

Comment: However, it already worked on my own.